# Shell tab-completion for service command broken as root

Tags: 12.04, bash, root, auto-completion

On most of our servers, tab completion of service names after typing in the service command no longer works, as root. It works just fine as non-root. This is on Ubuntu 12.04. I'm not sure how to approach troubleshooting this.

**Demonstrating:**

Tab completion works as the normal user `zachary`, who pressed tab to list completions in the first image:

[image: Tab completion works]

But as user `root`, it doesn't list services as completions (only files):

[image: Now it does not]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is disabled by default on Ubuntu.

Read your `/root/.bashrc`:

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#fi
```

Bash completion is *all commented out*. Apparently there's a reason for it I'm not aware of (recovery single user mode perhaps?).

The reason for why it does work when you do `sudo su`, `sudo -s`, `sudo bash` is that it doesn't really run `login` to make you completely root. When running `sudo su -` or `sudo -i` it really does completely logs you in as that user. Here, by example of the environment variable `$HOME`, more of this difference:

```
gert@gert-laptop:~$ id
uid=1000(gert) gid=1000(gert) groups=1000(gert),4(adm),7(lp),24(cdrom),27(sudo),[...]
gert@gert-laptop:~$ echo $HOME
/home/gert
gert@gert-laptop:~$ sudo -s
root@gert-laptop:~# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
root@gert-laptop:~# echo $HOME
/home/gert
root@gert-laptop:~# exit
gert@gert-laptop:~$ sudo su -
root@gert-laptop:~# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
root@gert-laptop:~# echo $HOME
/root
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I've figured it out, sort of.

Things that work:

- sudo -i
- sudo su -

Things that don't work:

- sudo -s
- sudo su
- sudo bash

So it appears to me that in the former case, you're actually creating a new login shell, so bashrc, profile, etc are loaded correctly, either from ~ or from /etc/skel. In the latter case you're just "executing bash as root" and not actually loading all those critical functions into the shell for autocomplete and the like.

Caveat: My explanation might be 100% wrong. But the top group does work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following steps to get completion for `sudo` in bash:

1. Open your `.bashrc`.
2. Insert the following lines and save the file
   `if [ "$PS1" ]; then`
   `complete -cf sudo`
   `fi`
   The `complete` command generates lists of completions for command names (`-c`) and files name (`-f`) for sudo.
3. Open a new bash and type `sudo -s`<kbd>Tab</kbd> or any other command you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with root not auto-completing. I unsuccessfully tried a couple other ways including messing around with the .bashrc and installing a couple packages. What finally worked for me was as simple as just running bash. So you do your `sudo su` and tab just lists (in `/root`)

```
root@xxxxxxxx:~# service<tab>
root@xxxxxxxx:~# service .<tab><tab>
./             .aptitude/     .bashrc        .viminfo  
../            .bash_history  .profile
```

`echo $SHELL` replies `/bin/bash` so I'm running bash, but it's not working. Now I run `bash` and my shell looks the same still.

```
root@xxxxxxxx:~# bash
root@xxxxxxxx:~# service <tab><tab>
acpid                        plymouth-upstart-bridge  
apache2                      portmap  
apparmor                     portmap-wait
```

Now it's working. *Just keep in mind that you'll have to double exit to exit the bash you just launched and then exit the `sudo su` session so you don't leave a root terminal open.*

```
root@xxxxxxxx:~# uname -mrs
Linux 3.8.0-33-generic x86_64  
root@xxxxxxxx:~# lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. What I tried is:

1. Run `/usr/sbin/visudo` as root user
2. Add this line to it then save and exit:

   `Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`
3. Open new session and try to run command now

That's it; you have done it.

Comment: How does this solve the problem? AFAIK those paths are already in the defaults anyway.